# Reassigning let variables

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I came across the following code in the Typescript docs:

```
function createSquare(config: SquareConfig): { color: string; area: number } {
    let newSquare = {color: "white", area: 100};
    if (config.color) {
        newSquare.color = config.color;
    }
    if (config.width) {
        newSquare.area = config.width * config.width;
    }
    return newSquare;
}
```

If let variables are only visible within their block scope - why does this not throw an error? newSquare is initialised, but then modified within a new block scope where (as I understand it) it should not be visible?

Comment: any blocks that are inside the current block will see the let variable too.

Comment: Within their block scope means that they are in the same block **OR** in a block within the defining block.

Comment: right, if you declared it in the first `if` statement, it would not be available outside of that if statement.

Comment: Two things that might help: those if blocks are nested within the function block where the variable is defined. Also, let and const variables whose values are complex (object, array) can be modified.

Comment: Why would this throw an error?

Comment: @evolutionxbox "newSquare is not defined" error if it wasn't in scope - but as others above have explained, it is in scope

Comment: @toskv gotcha, thanks